# Calculating binomial distribution in R

Tags: r, probability

I want to do some calculations on a binomial distribution Bin(100,0.55). In particular:

P[μₓ - σₓ ≤ X ≤ μₓ + σₓ]

I also want to calculate it using the normal approximation for the binomial:

f(x)=1/√(2πσ²) exp[-(x-μ)²/2σ²]

and attempt to do so using the Chebyshev inequality (say for k=2)

P[|X-μ| ≥ kσ] ≤ 1/k²

I would like to know if there is a relatively straightforward way to implement these calculations easily in ***R*** (that is, using in built functions rather than coding this manually).

Comment: Apologies if the question is not worded well. What I would like to ask is whether there is a simple way to calculate this in R? I understand that if I wanted to calculate it manually I would need to substitute using the binomial formula.

Comment: Given the edits, this seems a better fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

please check the help documentation for

```
dbinom
pbinom
qbinom
```

In general, for other distributions, this pattern **dDISTRIBUTION_NAME**, **pDISTRIBUTION_NAME**, **qDISTRIBUTION_NAME** still holds.